# If I increase the char value in my mysql database, will it blow up?

Tags: mysql

I have a column, char(9).  I want to increase it to char(10).  Will that hose up my database?  Can you just increase it like that without problems in the database?  Thanks.

Comment: Have you also considered using a varchar?

Comment: Yes, you can. Anyway, as said, considered using a `VARCHAR`.

Comment: @MarkByers yes, but I don't know if that will blow up either

Comment: If somethings going to blow up then theres not much you can do about it if you make the change since you are already using a fixed length data type - what applications are running on this DB?

Comment: @johnny: Well, perhaps you should ask that question next, because it seems likely that what you really need here is not a char(n) but a varchar. Unfortunately you haven't given enough information to be sure whether a char or varchar is more suitable.

Comment: It is OK as long as you don't try it the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

As long as nothing is depending on the char column being 9 characters. Mostly this should be ok (in terms of database continuing to function it should be fine), but you need to carefully consider if any software is using the column width for anything..

e.g. if software is expecting all values to be 9 characters (and it not trimming the string) you may find yourself encountering issues.

I suggest a varchar for variable length data

Answer (score 3):

If you change the column from `char(9)` to `char(10)` then MySQL will rebuild the entire table, right-padding the existing values with a single space. The execution time will depend on the size of the table due to the rebuild, so plan appropriately.

Comment: To further clarify, MySQL will also strip trailing spaces when you retrieve the value.

Comment: Yes, good point. The right-padding is done at the storage level since it's a fixed-width column, but those trailing spaces are ignored for comparison and retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this and didn't need to call the Bomb Squad, lol:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` CHANGE `myfield` `myfield` CHAR(10) CHARSET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL;
```